# How to insert elements into a list at specific positions after already inserting

Tags: python, list, numpy

I'm writting a program that takes to Xlsx files, compares them, then writes out the data in the form `fileA[0][0], fileB[0][0], diff(fileA[0][0], fileB[0][0])`. I calculated all the differences, but I'm struggling to place them in that format without hard coding a ton. I searched the Xlsx for the location of the specific column, and stored it at `where*` as an int. I interlace the two rows by

```
currentMasterRow  = ([x for x in itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.zip_longest(A[1],B[1]))])
```

My thought was to try

```
currentMasterRow = np.insert(currentMasterRow, ((whereApple * 2) + 2), AppleDifference)
currentMasterRow = np.insert(currentMasterRow, ((wherePear * 2) + 2), PearDifference)
currentMasterRow = np.insert(currentMasterRow, ((whereOrange * 2) + 2), OrangeDifference)
currentMasterRow = np.insert(currentMasterRow, ((whereGrape * 2) + 2), GrapeDifference)
currentMasterRow = np.insert(currentMasterRow, ((whereKiwi * 2) + 2), KiwiDifference)
currentMasterRow = np.insert(currentMasterRow, ((whereBanana * 2) + 2), BananaDifference)
currentMasterRow = np.insert(currentMasterRow, ((whereMango * 2) + 2), MangoDifference)
```

But the output seemed off. After thinking for a bit, I realized that every time I inserted, the position would change, so it was no longer accurate. My first thought was to increase the offset, but but I don't know the order columns are in. Lets say the insert locations were `[1,3,4,2]`, I wouldn't need to offset the '2' by '3', since it wouldn't be offset by '3' or '4'.

If there was a way to make a list of variables, sort it by largest to smallest, and do it in that order it should work. I think in C++ I could probably use pointers in that matter, but I don't know a way in python to do it.

Not every column has a difference to output. So realistically it could look like `fileA[X][0], fileB[X][0], diff(fileA[X][0], fileB[X][0]) fileA[X][1], fileB[X][1], fileA[X][2], fileB[X][2], diff(fileA[X][2], fileB[X][2])`

Comment: Are you certain that a list of lists is the right approach, rather than - for example - a dictionary of lists?

Comment: What would that look like in this scenario?